# explicit constructor not allowed in initializer-list<pair<std::string, my_type>>

Tags: c++

I wanted to create a string-container type that checks if the string it contains is valid at construction. In my opinion, it should be preferable if this class has an constructor that takes a std::string as an argument (just to make sure that no implicit type conversions happen).

But when I use this string-container in an `std::initializer_list` (and even further in a `std::unordered_multimap`) I get an error, if I define the constructor as explicit.
Is there a way to define the constructor as explicit and use it at the same time in a std::multimap? (i.e. a constructor-overload of a magic type I am currently not aware of)

I prepared the following minimal example that should show the point:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>

class constrained_string_container_t{
    public:
    // variant 1: works
    //constrained_string_container_t(const std::string& inst) : str{inst} {validate();}

    // variant 2: doesn't work
    explicit constrained_string_container_t(const std::string& inst) : str{inst} {validate();}
    explicit constrained_string_container_t(std::string&& inst) : str{std::move(inst)} {validate();}

    // variant 3: works
    //template<typename STR_T>
    //constrained_string_container_t(STR_T&& inst) : str{std::forward<STR_T>(inst)} {validate();}

    // variant 4: doesn't work
    //template<typename STR_T>
    //explicit constrained_string_container_t(STR_T&& inst) : str{std::forward<STR_T>(inst)} {validate();}

    void validate() {if (str == "abc") {throw std::runtime_error{"abc not allowed"};}}

    private:
    std::string str;
};

using pair_t = std::pair<std::string, constrained_string_container_t>;
using init_pair_list_t = std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, constrained_string_container_t>>;
using map_t = std::unordered_multimap<std::string, constrained_string_container_t>;

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    //suceeds for all variants
    pair_t p0{std::string{"test"}, std::string{"test2"}};

    //fails to compile for variant 2 and variant 4
    init_pair_list_t p1{{std::string{"test"}, std::string{"test2"}}};

    //fails to compile for variant 2 and variant 4
    init_pair_list_t p2{{"test"s, "test2"s}};

    //fails to compile for variant 2 and variant 4
    map_t m{{"test"s, "test2"s}};
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following errors (with gcc-10):

```
explicit_shit.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
explicit_shit.cpp:40:72: error: could not convert ‘{{std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"test"), std::allocator<char>()), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"test2"), std::allocator<char>())}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘init_pair_list_t’ {aka ‘std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, constrained_string_container_t> >’}
   40 |         init_pair_list_t p1{{std::string{"test"}, std::string{"test2"}}};
      |                                                                        ^
      |                                                                        |
      |                                                                        <brace-enclosed initializer list>
explicit_shit.cpp:43:48: error: could not convert ‘{{std::literals::string_literals::operator""s(const char*, std::size_t)(4), std::literals::string_literals::operator""s(const char*, std::size_t)(5)}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘init_pair_list_t’ {aka ‘std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, constrained_string_container_t> >’}
   43 |         init_pair_list_t p2{{"test"s, "test2"s}};
      |                                                ^
      |                                                |
      |                                                <brace-enclosed initializer list>
explicit_shit.cpp:46:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_multimap<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, constrained_string_container_t>::unordered_multimap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   46 |         map_t m{{"test"s, "test2"s}};
      |                                    ^
```

Comment: Well, you wanted to make sure that no implicit type conversions happen, so now you have to make your conversions explicit. As in `init_pair_list_t p1{{std::string{"test"}, constrained_string_container_t{std::string{"test2"}}}};`

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to compile

```
init_pair_list_t p1{{std::string{"test"}, std::string{"test2"}}};
```

your type `constrained_string_container_t` must be *implicitly* convertible from `std::string`, since the initialization of the elements of the `std::initializer_list` from the elements of the *braced-init-list* will use copy-initialization.

However, as I understand it, your concern is that `constrained_string_container_t` should not be constructed from something that the compiler might implicitly convert to `std::string`. So you've marked the constructors `explicit`. But then the previous thing doesn't work properly.

A possible fix is to have a constructor template that only participates in overload resolution if the argument type is *cv* `std::string`:

```
template <class T>
requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, std::string>
constrained_string_container_t(T&& inst) : str{std::forward<T>(inst)} {validate();}
```

See the full example here: https://godbolt.org/z/W791e4rGr

(You should probably also allow classes derived from `std::string`. How to do this is left as an exercise for the reader.)